# R: runif produces NAN

Tags: r

I want to generate some data which correspond to a quantile function. But the data need a `min` and a `max` value.

```
set.seed(30)
a1<-950 ; a2<-0; a3<-2.48; a4<-1.92
invcdf<-function (x)(a1+a2*a3*((-log(x))^(1/a4)))/(a3*((-log(x))^(1/a4))+1)
t<-invcdf(runif(2000,min=80,max=800))
```

When I use min and max in the runif function `NaN`'s are produced. 
How can I improve this code to avoid `NaN`'s? I can't change the parameters.

Comment: Your `invcdf` is likely wrong and the issue has little to do with `runif` itself. You should realize that `invcdf` is not defined for x outside the (0,1) range (see why? Hint: `(-log(x))^(1/a4)`).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317528/how-do-you-compute-negative-numbers-to-fractional-powers

Comment: `1/a4` is around 0.5 and `^0.5` is the same as taking the square root

Comment: @MbrMbr The problem is not the value of the exponent, but the value of the base. The power operation for a calculator *requires* (aside from trivial cases, like the exponent being 0 or 1) the base to be positive. So, for instance, `(-3)^(0.888)` is `NaN`. Even `(-27)^(1/3)` is `NaN`, although we know that the result is `-3`. Follow the link above to see why.

Comment: I can't vote for my own post. That's not so good. Maybe someone can downvote me. No joke.

Comment: The min and max value inside the runif function have to be between 0 and 1 (invcdf). In my case. Jesus!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't explain what exactly you are trying to do (which distribution are you trying to sample?), all I can do is interpret this as an attempt to generate random variable according to some distribution using its inverse CDF function. Because I don't know which it is, I can't comment on whether your implementation of it is correct.

However, when you use this method, you should know that the CDF function takes values between 0 and 1, as it is a cumulative density, starting at 0, and going to 1 in some limit.

The inverse of that function then only makes sense if you feed it values between 0 and 1, and that is where a possible error lies. `runif(2000,min=80,max=800)` generates random values between 80 and 800, way outside the `(0,1)` interval.

If you instead do this:

`t <- invcdf(runif(2000))`

We do get results (which happen to lie between 80 and 800 mostly):

[image]